# How to 2 UPDATE in One MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

in MySQL query
How to do 2 UPDATE in one Query, the query below:

```
UPDATE `stats` SET `coin` = coin + 500 WHERE `player` = 'userone'
UPDATE `stats` SET `coin` = coin - 500 WHERE `player` = 'usertwo'
```

Comment: @stuartd I think it would be perverse to use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` solution in that question for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` and `in`:

```
UPDATE `stats`
    SET `coin` = coin + (case when player = 'userone' then 500 else -500 end)
    WHERE `player` in ( 'userone', 'usertwo');
```

Comment: You beat me by seconds posting the answer using CASE

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE stats
SET coin = CASE player
            WHEN 'userone' THEN coin + 500
            WHEN 'usertwo' THEN coin - 500
           END
WHERE player IN ('userone', 'usertwo')
```